# MySQL SELECT statement doesn't stop when no rows are found

Tags: php, mysql

I expect this MySQL query to bomb out when it doesn't find the matching ID in the table:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='1' LIMIT 1") OR die("Boom!");
```

It doesn't. It just goes on processing with no error.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110021/selecting-row-from-mysql-if-id-matches/5110073#5110073

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE Condition` means "give me all rows that satisfy `Condition`" - to which "there are no rows that satisfy `Condition`" is a perfectly valid answer, not an error.

Comment: Maybe try to change id='1' to id=1?

Answer (score 6):

A select statement doesn't fail if it finds no rows - it just returns an empty result set.

You can check [`mysql_num_rows`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-num-rows.php) to see if any rows were found.

Answer (score 1):

The sql statement does not fail, it actually returns nothing.
Look here [How does "do something OR DIE()" work in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432454/how-does-do-something-or-die-work-in-php)

Comment: Thanks - just what I was looking to find out.

Answer (score 1):

A query only "fails" when you make a syntax or logical error in it.

A query returning no rows is still a valid query. Check the resultset that it returns to see how many results you get: in your case, check for there being '0'.

Answer (score -1):

Run the query from the command line using the [mysql command line client](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysql.html) to make sure the table is not corrupted.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the question. He's not wondering why no rows are returned, he's expecting `mysql_query` to return `false` in this case. But it's not supposed to, it only returns false when there's an error (e.g. a syntax error in the query or a problem connecting to the server).