# How to access to row according to id number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to reach my data for use in my app. I want to write with json_encode on my hosting. My purpose is; I send to it from my app and this id return me a row that it's row. But I cannot reach the row that I want. My PHP code always gives me first row. How can I fix it?

My php folder :

```
<?php
include ('ayar.php');

$id = $_POST["id"];



$bak = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from kullanici" );
$sayı = mysqli_fetch_row($bak);
$değer = mysqli_num_rows($bak);
echo($değer);
 echo(json_encode($sayı));


?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selecting row from mysql if id matches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5110021/selecting-row-from-mysql-if-id-matches)

Comment: Not php or phpmyadmin related.  Do some research on SQL.

Comment: ohhh ok. I started newly. I am updating my tags now.

Comment: As I saw, You have not mention `$id` in sql query !!!!, and `mysqli_fetch_row()` will return first row of table

Comment: @ShishilPatel I think your comment is a bit harsh, why not submit that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a WHERE to you MYSQL query.

```
$bak = mysqli_query($connect, "select * from kullanici WHERE id = {$id}" );
```

A safer way would be to use a prepared statement. Because you are not checking the parameter $id. This to prevent SQL injections.

Have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Thanks. Your answer and link. Your answer is working.

Comment: By the way ; İf I have just like this question. Should I use these tags ? (mysql , sql)

Comment: @BerkayIşıkoğlu Yes, and also the tag mysqli